# Tkinter python 3.5 choose files from file system and assign their path

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

How  can I assign the paths of three files (.csv and .xlsx) located in the file system of Windows dynamically into a python 3.5 script using the library Tkinter? In other words I want a script that allows the user to choose 3 files located in the file system of Windows and dynamically assign their path to three variables presented in the script (for example x, y and z) dynamically using TKinter.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20725056/get-a-files-directory-in-a-string-selected-by-askopenfilename Something like this one?

Comment: Yeah but I need also to add the name of the file to the path... for example "C:\Users\antony.lee\Desktop\python\five.xlsx".